# Disable root access to iptables. It is possible to disable root user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

It is possible to disable root user to change `iptables` rules or anything do with iptables, allowing to change rules for another user?

Comment: Assuming you could, then `root` would be able to restore that privilege, unless you bar that too, but root would still be able to unbar itself... What is the initial problem?

Comment: Yes, you are right, @xenoid, I did not thought about that, thanks for your thought! It would be better for secure exploitation of OS to use a unique password for iptables rules' changing. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Like @dirkt, I think this is an XY problem, in other words, you think a solution to some problem unknown to us is to prevent root from changing iptables. But you should state that problem (in another question) so that we can suggest solutions that are more in line with Unix/Linux usage.

Answer (score 1):

1) The root user will always be able to change `iptables`. You can't disable that.

2) `iptables` rules are system-wide, and not "per user". So root doesn't change "iptables rules for another user".

3) You can give another user root rights for specific programs e.g. with `sudo`. So that specific user would be able to call `iptables` to change the system-wide setting (and of course root would be still able to do it). If that is what you want.

4) This sounds suspiciously like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please edit the question and describe what you want to achieve, and why do you think you need to be able to disallow root to call `iptables`. I am pretty sure your real problem can be solved in a way that's compatible with Linux, using proper user and group account management.