# Use SELinux(?) to disable root access to iptables for procrastination

Tags: linux, iptables, selinux

This might not be a problem for you but I suffer from poor impulse control and as a result constant procrastination while in front of a computer. I can't procrastinate much on my phone because I bought a "dumb" phone specifically for this reason. Now, I have tried these to block me from visiting certain websites on my computer:

1. Install extensions to browsers: I erase them
2. Edit hosts file or iptables: I sudo edit them
3. Parental control software: I sudo kilall
4. Cron job: I disable
5. Giving sudo password to a trusted friend: I need the password to install programming tools and libraries on the computer and they get annoyed when I ask the password too many times
6. I live in a complex that provides routers so I don't have any access to router configuration. I also can't install my own router because they will block it.

A similar question was asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213187/unbypassable-way-to-block-all-distracting-sites-content-on-ubuntu) and here [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1372899/disable-root-access-to-iptables-it-is-possible-to-disable-root-user) but they came to the conclusion that it isn't possible. The bottomline is, as long as I have admin access to edit/erase anything I can and do do it. What I really need is basically two admin accounts with mutually exclusive roles:

1. Regular superuser: can do everything regular Linux superuser can do **except** editing iptables or hosts file.
2. Impulse control user: can do **nothing except edit iptables or hosts file.** (and execute nano for this purpose)

You give the second user's password to a trusted friend that would only give it to you in case of an emergency and there's a social barrier that keeps you from constantly asking for this password without being annoying. This way you have the power to install tools and update the computer while still protecting you from your procrastinating self.

The only thing I found so far that would enable me to do such a thing is SELinux, but even the most beginner tutorial is very involved (in terms of knowledge) and I am afraid of locking myself out of my computer permanently if I do something wrong because I am not familiar with it.

Since what I am trying to do is relatively simple, is there any way to achieve this without SELinux or if I have to use it, is there an easy and straightforward way to set up SELinux in this way?

I am actually surprised no one has done something like this before (that or I can't seem to find it). To be clear, I am **not** looking for a lecture on how I should learn to control my impulses instead of using such tools. I hope this question and answers help someone like me in the future.